# How to use json column in the WHERE clause as a condition

Tags: sql, oracle

The question is stated in the title and below is an example of the data

```
insert into table A values('a','b', {'key':'value'});
```

And I would like to be able to select this row based on the key-value pair using the WHERE clause. How can I do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `JSON_VALUE`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tableA t
WHERE JSON_VALUE(col3, '$.key') LIKE 'some_value'
```

This assumes that the column which contains the JSON value `{'key':'value'}` is called `col3`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. =)

Comment: @Mox Happy to help you out.

Comment: if the key is under another key ex: {"quote":{'key':'value'}} is called col3, you can use `WHERE JSON_VALUE(col3, '$.quote.key') LIKE 'some_value'`.
I had this case, I wanted to share it, it might help.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using PostgreSQL then use below query

```
select * from table_name where column_name->>'key_name' = 'value_name';
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is solution that's work for me:

```
column_name->'$.key'
```

Tested with mysql server 5.7.27

Comment: good to know that works for mysql. does it work for oracle db?